# Game slowing down and becoming unplayable

Tags: javascript, html, performance, html5-canvas

I have a problem with my game in that it starts off fast and after a few seconds in it has noticeably slowed down, I have taken out bits of code and added them in one at a time to see what is slowing it down, and it is when I create the array of blocks and print them to the screen that is causing the lag.

//Block section

-Loop from 1 to 10
-Create shape object
-push on array
-end

-Loop through Array
-Paint Shape to screen

There is a lot of bugs in the game , its still in the process of being completed :) :)

http://jsfiddle.net/s2NCx/1/

```
var canvas;
 var ctx;
 var dx = 5;
 var dy = 5;
 var x = 460;
 var y = 480;
 var a = 500;
 var b = 570;
 var WIDTH = 1000;
 var HEIGHT = 600;
 var x1 = 0,
     y1 = 0;
 var dx1 = 5,
     dy1 = 5;
 var myblocks = [];
 ball = new setcircle(x, y, 10, "purple");
 //paddel = new square(x,y,100,20,"purple");

//initate
 function init() {
     canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
     ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
     return setInterval(draw, 10);

 }

//creates an array of blocks and prints to screen
 function block() {


     var p = 40;
     for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

         myblocks.push(new Shape(p, 10, 90, 20, "#333"))
         p = p + 91;
     }

     for (i in myblocks) {
         oblock = myblocks[i];
         ctx.fillStyle = oblock.fill1;
         ctx.fillRect(oblock.a, oblock.b, oblock.w, oblock.h);

     }
 }

 //draws and moves ball
 function movecircle(ball) {

     ball.x += dx;
     ball.y += dy;
     if (ball.x <= 0) dx = 5;
     else if (ball.x >= 980) dx = -5;
     if (ball.y <= 0) dy = 5;
     else if (ball.y >= 590) dy = -5;
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.fillStyle = ball.fill;
     ctx.arc(ball.x, ball.y, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
     ctx.fill();



 }

// checks if collides
 function isCollide(r, c) {

     // copyed from stackoverflow
     var cx = Math.abs(c.x - r.a - r.w / 2);
     var xDist = r.w / 2 + c.r;
     if (cx > xDist) return false;
     var cy = Math.abs(c.y - r.b - r.h / 2);
     var yDist = r.h / 2 + c.r;
     if (cy > yDist) return false;
     if (cx <= r.w / 2 || cy <= r.w / 2) return true;
     var xCornerDist = cx - r.w / 2;
     var yCornerDist = cy - r.h / 2;
     var xCornerDistSq = xCornerDist * xCornerDist;
     var yCornerDistSq = yCornerDist * yCornerDist;
     var maxCornerDistSq = c.r * c.r;
     return xCornerDistSq + yCornerDistSq <= maxCornerDistSq;
 }

//ball object
 function setcircle(x, y, r, fill) {

     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
     this.r = r;
     this.fill = fill;
 }
//shape object
 function Shape(a, b, w, h, fill) {

     this.a = a;
     this.b = b;
     this.w = w;
     this.h = h;
     this.fill1 = fill;

 }
//keyboard inout
 function doKeyDown(evt) {
     switch (evt.keyCode) {
         case 38:
             /* Up arrow was pressed */
             if (b - dy > 0) {
                 b -= dy;
             }
             break;
         case 40:
             /* Down arrow was pressed */
             if (b + dy < HEIGHT) {
                 b += dy;
             }
             break;
         case 37:
             /* Left arrow was pressed */
             if (a - dx > 0) {
                 a -= dx;
             }
             break;
         case 39:
             /* Right arrow was pressed */
             if (a + dx < WIDTH) {
                 a += dx;
             }
             break;
     }
 }

 function changedirection(ball) {
     dy = -dy;






 }

 function update() {


     //check if ball hits paddle
     if (isCollide(paddel, ball)) {
         changedirection(ball);
         ctx.fillStyle = "purple";
         ctx.fillRect(200, 200, 100, 100);
     }
     //check if ball hits block
     for (i in myblocks) {
         if (isCollide(myblocks[i], ball)) {
             changedirection(ball);
             ctx.fillStyle = "purple";
             ctx.fillRect(200, 200, 100, 100);

         }
     }

 }



 function draw() {
     ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
     movecircle(ball);
     block();
     paddel = new Shape(a, b, 100, 20, "purple");
     ctx.fillStyle = paddel.fill1;
     ctx.fillRect(paddel.a, paddel.b, paddel.w, paddel.h);
     update();
 }
 init();
 window.addEventListener('keydown', doKeyDown, true);
```

//UPDATE:

I have removed the initalisation of the blocks and placed into the init method and this has speed up the game significantly.

Comment: first step is to post what you have tried (profiling? removing code? searched for optimisations?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running your code and using the profiler built in to chrome shows that your app is spending more than 50% of it's time in the `block` function.

[image]

Looking at a heap snapshot taken after a while show that a lot of the heap space is taken up by `Shape` objects.

[image]

Looking at the source of `block` we see that you're pushing 10 new `Shape` objects each time `block` is called. That is why your app is slowing down. You should check out these profiling tools as it is a very good way to learn where the bottlenecks are in an application.

As for a simple way to at least make the application not slow down so quickly you could add:

```
myblocks = [];
```

in the begining of the `block` function.

Comment: Cheers, never new there was an application like this, it will help alot in the future !

Answer (score 2):

The size of `myblocks` increases by 10 in `block()` which is called every 10 milliseconds (your `setInterval`) by `draw()`. After one second you have 1000 blocks.

Answer (score 2):

The slowdown is caused by the fact that you are re-calling

```
 block();
 paddel = new Shape(a, b, 100, 20, "purple");
```

(that recreate the paddle shape and blocks) at every iteration of draw(), called every 10 ms